# Is there a differene between int x[] and int *x?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm studying a function to search for a number where that goes as the following..

```
int sequential_search (int num, int a[], int size);
```

And in main , a is defined as the following.

```
int *a;
a = new int[size];
```

So I was wondering if its the same thing..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When used as function parameter then there is no difference.

```
int sequential_search (int num, int a[], int size);
```

is equivalent to

```
int sequential_search (int num, int *a, int size);
```

Otherwise both are different: `int x[]` declare `x` as an array of `int`s while `int *x` declare `x` as a pointer to `int`.